# Python regex function to only keep decimal ffom dataframe of strings

Tags: python, regex

How can I use the `regex.resub()` function to only keep the values '**0.000068**' '**0.000064**' '**0.000087**' in the following dataframe of strings that follows this pattern:

'h.1    0.000068\nName: 2014-05-08 00:00:00, dtype: float64'

'h.1    0.000064\nName: 2014-05-09 00:00:00, dtype: float64'

'h.1    0.000087\nName: 2014-05-12 00:00:00, dtype: float64'
etc...

I tried `df.applymap(lambda x: re.sub(r'[\(\),]', '', str(x)))` but it only removes the comma.

Comment: The purpose of resub is to replace the string with the regex function. Do you want to remove the values ('0.000068' '0.000064' '0.000087') from the string or just getting the values? Asking just to be sure to post the proper answer.

Comment: @lucas_7_94 i want to only keep the values ('0.000068' '0.000064' '0.000087'), so remove all the rest

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pattern

```
^.*\b(\d+\.\d+)\n.*$
```

and substitute with `\1`.

```
strings = ['h.1 0.000068\nName: 2014-05-08 00:00:00, dtype: float64',
           'h.1 0.000064\nName: 2014-05-09 00:00:00, dtype: float64',
           'h.1 0.000087\nName: 2014-05-12 00:00:00, dtype: float64']
for s in strings:
    num = re.sub(r'^.*\b(\d+\.\d+)\n.*$', r'\1', s)
    print(num)
    num = re.sub(r'^(.*)(\d\.\d+)(\n.*)',r'\2',s)
    print(num)
```

output

```
0.000068
0.000064
0.000087
```

Comment: @Thefourthbird : Thank you for your help. I've modified my answer.

Comment: No worries, all is well :-) I will remove the comments.